# bootstrap pagination with bootstrap Collapse

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have built a screen that has many bootstrap collapse panels, I would like to use pagination to make the screen easier to use.  Is this possible? I have been looking for code samples of this, but I have only found examples of pagination, and not pagination with collapse.  Firstly, is this possible, if so, does any know of or have some sample code i could see.   Code below

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">Column 1 </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">Column 2s  </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">Column 3 </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">Column 4 <span class="label-info pull-right">View <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Div1">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">Column 1 </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">Column 2s  </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">Column 3 </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">Column 4 <span class="label-info pull-right">View <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="Div1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post you collapse panel code, or create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com) so that we can see what you have so far?

Comment: added code snippet, and explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example (using your panel groups) that uses a simple pagination plugin with the Bootstrap pagination component.

### http://www.bootply.com/120489